# Creating a template for a Writer-based calendar (diary)

Tags: templates, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

I'm currently working on a calendar for the new year – a daily planner, a diary! Something for GTD (Getting things done) based on a diary with planner options. It is created in OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

The questions are:

- How do I get the months that are shown in the bottom to the footer of the layout?
- How can I manage to get the months for the whole year?

The months are shown below. For each week in each month we have a little overview that shows:

- the current month
- the previous month
- the following month

[image]

Note: This an example for the month of March. How can I do this for the whole year? It is pretty difficult to create the calendar in the bottom.

By the way, there are more infos that go into the calendar. I do an import of the data. 
I import 365 texts called "Losungen" that are biblical notes and verbs. See here:

[image]

There's no problem with the import of all those data. The only thing is: How do I create the calendar "images" in the bottom?